# Wrong axis values of Gamepad in Matlab's Psychtoolbox

Tags: matlab, gamepad, psychtoolbox

I'm using the [Gamepad](http://docs.psychtoolbox.org/Gamepad) interface in Psychtoolbox together with a Logitech Attack3 joystick and the following code:

```
while ~Gamepad('GetButton', 4, 1)
    force = Gamepad('GetAxis', 4, 2);
    force = force / 32768;
    zoomFactor = 0.1 * force;
    zoom(1 + zoomFactor);
end
```

It's supposed to get the vertical axis value from the joystick and use that to calculate the zoom factor (toy problem: zoom in and out of picture).

When querying the axis value, I get strange results. If I move the joystick, the axis value changes as expected. However, when I release the joystick back into resting, the axis value should return 0, but it just stays at the last displayed value. Basically, the joystick only registers movement away from the center but not the returning motion back to the resting position.

Comment: What are `4,1` and `4,2` ?

Comment: `Gamepad('GetButton', 4, 1) = Gamepad('GetButton', gamepadIndex, buttonIndex);`

`Gamepad('GetAxis', 4, 2) = Gamepad('GetAxis',  gamepadIndex, axisIndex)  in this case the y-axis`

Comment: If you move the joystick back forward again, after resting, is the movement again registered?

Comment: Yes, it is registered again.